# net time command - Service is not running

Tags: windows, domain

My computer is in a domain, I log on by local account, and then I excute this command `net time /domain`, then an error is displayed: Service is not running, please type `NET HELPMSG 2184` for more help.

I don't know what's wrong, and after I typed `NET HELPMSG 2184`, just a `service is not running` is displayed.

So what I want to know is which service should I start.

Thank you.

Comment: From what I can gather, the `net` command relies on the Computer Browser service, which itself relies on SMBv1, which is now disabled by default [because it is very insecure] - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Storage-at-Microsoft/Stop-using-SMB1/ba-p/425858

Comment: @Tetsujin  So what should I do to solve this problem, I'm using windows 10, and there is no service named Computer Browser.

Comment: You need to find another way to achieve your goal. `net` is gone, as is Computer Browser & SMBv1.

Answer (score 1):

Turning comments into answer for any future googlers...

From what I can gather, the net command relies on the Computer Browser service, which itself relies on SMBv1, which is now disabled by default [because it is very insecure] - [Microsoft Technet: Stop using SMB1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Storage-at-Microsoft/Stop-using-SMB1/ba-p/425858)

Therefore, you need to find another way to achieve your goal - net is gone, as is Computer Browser & SMBv1.